# Iterating Through A block With Different Types of Data

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, mongomapper

I am currently trying to iterate through a set of data but there are three different data types.  Two are mad-lib styles sets of answers that need to be placed into context (ie there is a whole sentence [form data would be inserted] and the sentence continues) and the third is just block of text.

Is there a way to do this where messages can be sorted by date regardless of type? I know loading partials is not the best practice way of handling this but could really use some more guidance on how to make this work.

Wish.all wont work because of the different types.

Comment: Can you describe a little more your problem and add a first cut of what your documents would look like?